# How can I do math for values ​given in TextEditingController?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    late final TextEditingController _weight = TextEditingController()
  late final TextEditingController _height = TextEditingController()
```

For example, for these two TextEditingControllers, I want to collect the values ​​entered by the user and print them in Text. How do I code this?

Answer (score 0):

You access the text by checking the `text` property. In your example, e.g.:

```
_weight.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse `text` property like this:

```
final _weightValue = double.tryParse(_weight.text);
final _heightValue = double.tryParse(_height.text);
```

I suggest you force keyboard to insert only numbers with:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

in your `TextField`